# Firebase error: live db not local "this.getPriority(...).isEmpty is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If answer needs more info or updating, please ask.

Expected:
Retrieve data from the database, both firebase firestore  and firebase  Realtime database

Actual:
Failed GET req with error:

```
"this.getPriority(...).isEmpty is not a function"
```

Firebase works fine locally when performing a GET req, as of 2 days ago, it worked on the DB fine with 2 mnths of stability.

I receive this error when performing a postman request.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "this.getPriority(...).isEmpty is not a function"
}
```

I know getPriority is a method on datasnapshot, I think for the RTDB.

this is the function i think in question:

```
export const RTDBMeters: (id: string, p: string) => Promise<number> =
async (id, p) => {
    const treesRef = await admin.database().ref(`/${p}/stats/${id}`);
    if (treesRef) {
        return await treesRef.once("value").then(i => {
            if (i.exists()) {
                return i.val() + 0;
            } else {
                log({'stats value does not exist': id})
                return 0;
            }
        });
    } else {
        log({'stats value location does not exist': id})
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='../apixel.json' tsc -w | firebase serve --only functions",
    "dev": "tsc -w | firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json | firebase emulators:start --import=./firestore_emulator_data",
    "dev:public": "tsc -w | firebase emulators:start --import=./ --export-on-exit",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "ts-mocha --reporter spec --require @babel/register",
    "test:watch": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='apixel-test.json' ts-mocha -w --reporter spec --require @babel/register --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.6"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "stripe": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.5",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha": "^8.0.1",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include where are you using this.getProperty().isEmpty?

Comment: I am not using it, it's the error read out. I think I solved this but cannot remember.